# Skip error 'Variable not defined' on not set object with Option Explicit

Tags: excel, vba

I've wrote an Excel application, let's call it *MasterWb* containing a few sheets e.g. (codenames): *wsFirst, wsSecond, wsThird*.

**1. What I would like to achieve**

I want to have the second workbook - the copy of *MasterWb* but without sheet *wsThird*. Let's call it *ClientWb*.

**2. How I achieve my goal now**

Simply my app has a macro prepareClientsWb which:
-creates the copy (*ClientWb*)  of the *MasterWb* using *SaveCopyAs* method 
-opens *ClientWb* and removes *wsThird* sheet and close it with save

**3. What the problem is**

I use *Workbook_Open* event in my app to prepare visibility of the sheets at opening

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     ' xlSheetVisible
        wsFirst.Visible = xlSheetVisible

     ' xlSheetHidden
        wsSecond.Visible = xlSheetHidden

     ' xlSheetVeryHidden
        wsThird.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

 End Sub
```

And the problem is that I can't use Option Explicit and worksheet codenames at the same time: of course an error occure *variable not defined* when I run generated clientWb ("wsThird" is not recognized). At the moment I don't use Option Explicit and I use On Error Resume Next statement. What is more elegant solution to handle my problem? I suppose it could be really easy, but I haven't got idea what is the best practice for this...

I can't use names or indexes instead codenames because it could be changed a lot.
I won't use templates, because the app is still developing and it's quite problematic for me to make changes in two workbooks.
I won't store part of the code in another module and remove this module while creating *clientWb*- it seems quite difficult to me and probably require *Trust Access to the VBA project object model* which I would avoid if possible. Or...

**4. Maybe using conditional compilation?**

...but isn't it using a sledgehammer to crack a nut :-)

For example create additional sheet *wsConditionalConst* with bool value in A1 range (0 *masterWb*, 1 *clientWb*) or check if wsThird exists or another way to determinate if we are in *masterWb* or *ClientWb* and store this information in *isMasterWorkbook* boolean variable. I don't know if can we use conditional variables instead of consts- just an idea.

```
 Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     ' xlSheetVisible
        wsFirst.Visible = xlSheetVisible

     ' xlSheetHidden
        wsSecond.Visible = xlSheetHidden

     ' xlSheetVeryHidden
      #If isMasterWorkbook = True Then
            wsThird.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
      #End If

 End Sub
```

Maybe there is a simple way to change/add Conditional Compilation Argument via VBA code instead of changing it manually in project properties? I don't know if it is even possible, haven't ever tried it.

In my real case my app is quite complex (~2k lines of code with login, a lot of sheets preparations such as turning off gridlines, headers ect. to make sure the app is as readable as possible), I have much more sheets in MasterWb than in example above (about 15 sheets) and I remove few of them while creating ClientWb.

I am sorry for the title- I have no idea how to explain it in english short easy way.

Comment: `wsFirst` is not a codename. If you want it to represent a code name, you need to declare it as such, and then `Set` it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I understood that it is the codename, but the problem occurs after that sheet is deleted in the copy of the master workbook.

Comment: Why do you think that at the time the `Workbook_Open` event is triggered, that `wsFirst` represents any type of sheet code_name?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - I'm guessing OP simplified for the purpose of this question, but it sounds like the codenames were changed in the master workbook to `wsFirst`, `wsSecond`, `wsThird` and so on... but those seem to just be example names.

Comment: I set codenames in properties window, so e.g. Debug.Print wsFirst.CodeName returns wsFirst :)

Comment: If your problem arises when you delete a worksheet in the master WB, then in your workbook_open event code, just test for the presence of the various worksheets before you do anything else.

Comment: ^ One possibility might be to loop through all worksheets and test their codenames for a match against the list of expected codenames.

Comment: all these would still cause compiler errors with the use of `Option Explicit`

Comment: @ArcherBird - yep, but I don't see any way around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would change your workbook open code:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
    Select Case ws.CodeName
        Case "wsFirst"
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Case "wsSecond"
            ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        Case "wsThird"
            ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    End Select
Next ws

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this. Have a function that finds a worksheet using its code name, or if not found returns `Nothing`. Then use that function to get the worksheets if they exist and set their visibility.

```
Public Function GetWorksheet(codeName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook
        If ws.codeName = codeName Then
            Set GetWorksheet = ws
            Exit Function
        End If

        '//If you get here, we didn't find it
        Set GetWorksheet = Nothing
    Next
End Function
```

Now your Workbook_Open event looks like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
     ' xlSheetVisible
    Set ws = GetWorksheet("wsFirst")
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible

     ' xlSheetHidden
    Set ws = GetWorksheet("wsSecond")
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden

     ' xlSheetVeryHidden
    Set ws = GetWorksheet("wsThird")
    If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

 End Sub
```